# PHP - ob_flush - clean old text and print new text in loop

Tags: php, flush

I'm trying to create a script which will be print text in for loop. Here is my script:

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    sleep(3);
    echo $i;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

?>
```

But this script sum every loop text. I want to clear buffer every loop and then print new text. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean clear the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the body using JavaScript, by example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    sleep(3); // usleep(300000);
    echo '<script>document.body.innerHTML="'.$i.'";</script>';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
?></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks!